# Decrease a <div> opacity as it gets closer to a linked anchor point

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a "scroll down" button on my website, which, when pressed will take you down to a specified anchor point. I currently have this button set to fade in and out, but this causes issues with the overlay and appears jumpy, and I would like to have it so the opacity decreases gradually as you move nearer to the point.

I would like to implement something similar to this:

```
var target = $('.godown'),
  targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;

  if (scrollPercent >= 0) {
    target.css('opacity', 1 - scrollPercent);
  }
});
```

However, this does not seem to work with my codepen, [here](https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/YzqKXQK). So am currently using a standard fade in/fade out, which looks jerky as it pops through the overlay and is not what I want. I would like to implement the above code into my site, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.godown').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.godown').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400);
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}

.godown a {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1vh;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.godown a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

#scroller a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#scroller a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>

<body style="background-color: red;">
  <section id="scroller" class="godown">
    <div>
      <a href="#anchor"><span></span>Scroll</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p id="anchor">anchor point</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>





</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the distance of: the distance of the element to scroll to from top (`offsetTop)` and the top of the scroll bar's Y position. This way, the script can assess whether the **top** of the scroll bar's Y position has already passed the element to scroll to. This will work with your current circumstance since you scroll to the top most of the element.

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    // offsetTop will be computed based on the closest relatively positioned parent element
    // since your anchor has none, this will return distance to document top
    let destination_y = $("#anchor")[0].offsetTop;
    let scrollbar_y = (window.scrollY); // top of scrollbar y position

    // subtract 1 to generate the css opacity level based on ratio
    let opacity = 1 - (scrollbar_y / destination_y); 
    $(".godown").css("opacity", opacity);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, although, I just tried this using a video header...and it's acting very strange. See here: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/qBZWeKV

Comment: your video has a higher z-index - therefore it is on top of the `#scroller`. just give the `#scroller` element a non-static position & and a higher z-index so that it will be on top of the video element